# Custom Controller URL Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, controllers, admin-controller

I need the correct URL for my form action! 
In `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customertab/action.phtml`
This is file code, Is there any things I'm missing?

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/customertab_customertab/reset"); ?>" method="post">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />                        
    <input type="submit" value="Post This Form" />
</form>
```

In app/code/local/Sean/CustomerTab/etc/config.xml I have:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomerTab>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Sean_CustomerTab>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customertab>
                    <file>customertab.xml</file>
                </customertab>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <customertab before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sean_CustomerTab_Adminhtml</sean_customertab>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customertab>
                <class>Sean_CustomerTab_Block</class>
            </customertab>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

In app/code/local/Sean/CustomerTab/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomerTab/CustomerTabController.php:

```
<?php

class Sean_CustomerTab_Adminhtml_CustomerTab_CustomerTabController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    function resetAction()
    {
        die("Sean was here controller");
    }
}
```

When I click the form submit button it takes me to mywebsite.com/index.php/power/customertab_customertab/reset/

and it's a 404 Not Found

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `<frontName>` is **customertab**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("customertab/customertab/reset"); ?>" method="post">
```

Dont forget to **add form key**

```
   <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Comment: added this but still not getting to the controller

Comment: I got it working, and I needed this for it to work as well!

Answer (score 0):

Change your config.xml code

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <customertab before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sean_CustomerTab_Adminhtml</customertab>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Your controller file path also need to change:

Before:

```
app/code/local/Sean/CustomerTab/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomerTabController.php
```

After:

```
app/code/local/Sean/CustomerTab/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomerTab/CustomerTabController.php
```

Change your controller class:

before:

```
Sean_CustomerTab_Adminhtml_CustomerTabController
```

After

```
Sean_CustomerTab_Adminhtml_CustomerTab_CustomerTabController
```

Your url is: `adminhtml/customertab_customertab/reset`

Comment: I did this exactly and still not working

Comment: i'll update my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

In the class Sean_CustomerTab_Adminhtml_CustomerTab_CustomerTabController

Because CustomerTabController has 2 words and both are capitalized.

The form action had to be:

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/customertab_customerTab/reset"); ?>" method="post">
```

In Magento the first letter from the controller doesn't matter if it's capitalized or not but any letter after the first matters or it won't work!  Just an annoying tip for anyone not getting their controller to work sigh.  But thanks for your answers everyone! Also shoutout to Prashant Valanda for telling me to input the form key that was required as well!